# libquickfix.a is not generated for QuickFix C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, quickfix

I am trying to build QuickFix(1.15.1) library on Linux CentOS release 6.10. I have done following steps

1. Downloaded QuckfixFix tar quickfix-1.15.1.tar.gz
2. Extracted tar file using command
   tar -xvf quickfix-1.15.1.tar.gz
3. run command in quickfix directory: ./configure
4. run command in quickfix directory: make
5. Found libquickfix.so generated but not libquickfix.a

**What needs to be done to generate libquickfix.a?**

Comment: Try `./configure --help` to find the option for building a static library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`configure` has an option:

- `--enable-static` - build static libraries

So:

```
./configure --enable-static
make -j
```

and then you'll find the static library here:

```
lib/libquickfix.a
```